# Weak convergence imply bounded sequences at all sample points?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space, with a sequence of random variables $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ defined on it. Suppose $Y_n\xrightarrow{\ d\ }Y$. Can we say that for (almost) every $\omega\in\Omega$, $\{Y_n(\omega)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence?

I wondered whether such a result is true while studying convergence in law. However, I see no reason for it to be true given the fact that random variables which are defined on different probability spaces may also converge in distribution. But I could neither prove it, nor find a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can even have that there exist no $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $(Y_n(\omega))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be bounded.

For instance, let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in(0,1)^{\mathbb N}$ be dense in $(0,1)$. Then define $U_n=mod(U-x_n,1)$, i.e. $U_n=U-x_n$ if $U\ge x_n$, and $U_n=U-x_n+1$ otherwise. For all $n$ let $Y_n=1/U_n$. It poses no challenge to show that $U_n$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Therefore, $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y=1/U$ (it is even constant in distribution).

Yet, let $\omega\in\Omega$. Then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ which converges from below to $U(\omega)$, so that $U_{n_k}(\omega)$ converges to $0$ as $k$ goes to $+\infty$, hence $Y_{n_k}$ goes to $+\infty$ with $k$. We deduce that $(Y_n(\omega))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not bounded.